# Using a board when studs don't line up

Tags: drywall, walls, mounting

I need to hang up a track in my garage that will be used to hang bikes. The track is from The Container Store and looks like this.

[image: track that will be hung on the wall]

It has holes every 8 inches so that it lines up with studs. I'm not sure why but the area where I'm hanging the track has two studs right next to each other which causes the track only to line up with 2 studs. I originally had the track hanging with drywall studs but the track had started to come off the wall a bit with just a couple things hanging from it like a ladder. Since I want to hang bikes I'd like to strengthen the track.

Can I just attach a 2x4 that is screwed into the studs and then mount the track on the 2x4? Would that provide the strength I need provided I use the correct screws to mount the board to the wall.

Here is what the wall looks like. You can see the studs next to each other along with the original mounting location of the track.

[image: picture of wall showing studs next to each other]

Comment: If only 4 holes with 8 inch spacing, then it can only be screwed to two studs(16 or 24 inch  centres).  Using a piece of wood is good.

Comment: The side by side studs were used because the top framing is joined at the location.

Comment: This appears to be elfa. I have installed these in two houses. I have sometimes drilled an extra hole to go into a stud. The special elfa drywall anchors are designed for drywall but your drywall does not go all the way up to the top plate. It appears to be unattached except at the studs. This makes use of the drywall anchors questionable unless you would put blocking across the top and properly fasten the drywall to the blocking.

Comment: I am curious as to why you chose the stud on the right of the double studs. If you had lined your hole up with the left of the two studs then the hole 16 inches to the left and/or right would have hit a stud as well. (*It appears so in the photo anyway*)  I agree with jack, drill a hole at the location for every stud.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could also simply redrill new holes to match the framing. 2 or 3 new holes near the ones that are there will not weaken the bar. The holes look oversized for a range of fasteners, you could use smaller holes if you are using 1/4" lag bolts for example.

Comment: Do both those studs next to each other, just because, half of those holes are wall anchors. If it's aluminum, use washers.

Comment: Elfa sell special wood screws for going into studs and special drywall anchors. These support tracks are steel.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that is exactly what you want to do. Have the 2x4 extend past the five studs shown in your picture and make sure your screws/bolts go at least 1" into the studs. They can go further if you're sure there's no wires through the studs.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is a common solution; mounting another piece of wood that can accommodate what you are hanging.  For bikes, you should use some lag screws to attach the piece of wood.

Comment: He means lag screws, not a bolt.